# How to override scrolling behaviour when dragging a cell of collection view using drag & drop delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, wwdc

I have implemented a collection view with drag and drop delegates as described in [WWDC 2017 Drag Drop Collection View](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/223/). The purpose of my collection view is to reorder within its cell. Now, here's my problem I want to make it scroll automatically when I drag the cell (after the long press) out of the collection view. I want to make it scroll to the down direction when I drag it to under my collection view and scroll it to Up when I drag it top and outside the collection view. Besides I'm not satisfied with the built-in auto scrolling.